# Is there a way to combine Server Binding and Ajax Binding to eliminate the extra request made in Ajax Binding on a Kendo grid?

Tags: ajax, data-binding, grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

By default the Kendo Grid for ASP.NET MVC will perform server side requests and load the page and grid on a single request. However, when configured for ajax binding the Kendo Grid for ASP.NET MVC will make ajax requests after the page is loaded which requires one extra request (one for the page and one extra for the data used by the grid). Is there a way to combine server binding and ajax binding to eliminate the extra request made in ajax binding alone? All I'm looking is to load the data for the page and grid at the same request (like Server Side Binding) for the first time and use ajax binding for subsequent requests. To disable the initial load on ajax binding we can disable the AutoBind Configuration Option (autoBind:false) of the grid. Now, I need a way to show the data on the grid while the autobind option is disabled. Any idea????

Comment: Not that I am aware of, unless you want to dig into their source code.  However, by option for AJAX aren't you inherently accepting that there are going to be elements of the DOM that are independent of the main request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind the Grid initially you should either pass your collection to the Grid method.

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<Customers>(theCollectionOfCustomersWhichWillBeUsedInitially)
//...
```

Or you could pass it to the **BindTo** method (which is actually the same ;)

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<Customers>()
.Name("someName")
.BindTo(sameCollectionasAbove)
```